# firebird embedded Java

Tags: java, firebird, embedded

Как указать относительный путь для embedded Firebird?
Вот так не работает: `jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/exam.fdb`

Comment: Может так попробовать `jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:<database>` ?

Comment: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq350/

Comment: Так с абсолютным путем работает: String strDatabasePath = "/Users/svetlanailina/Desktop/JAVAFX/JavaFX12_02/EXAM.FDB";
String strURL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:" + strDatabasePath + "?lc_ctype=WIN1251;sql_dialect=3"; А вот так с embedded не работает: String strURL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:EXAM.FDB";